# PHP MySQL User Profile Page

Tags: php, mysql, database, user-profile

I have a PHP login/register system and it's working fine. I also have a `profile.php` page which is used to show the currently logged in user's informations. For now, I want to do this, if the user is logged in and goes to `profile.php`, they will see their own profile page with their informations, but if the user navigates to `profile.php?id=2` page, they must see the profile whose ID is 2. It is almost done, but when I change the `id?=2`, only the `ID` changes. Any idea why is it not working?

`profile.php` CODE:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   // If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
   if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
       header('Location: /admin/index.php');
       exit;
   }
   $DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
   $DATABASE_USER = 'root';
   $DATABASE_PASS = '';
   $DATABASE_NAME = 'phplogin';
   $con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
   }

   $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT username, realname, password, email, second_email, sex, age,  country, city, timestamp FROM accounts WHERE id = ?');

   $stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($username, $realname, $password, $email, $second_email, $sex, $age,         $country, $city, $timestamp);
   $stmt->fetch();
   $stmt->close();
   if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != "") {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
   } else {
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
   }

   $mysqli = $con;

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
exit();

}

## query database

# fetch data from mysql database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = {$id} LIMIT 1";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
$user = $result->fetch_array();
} else {
echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}</p>";
exit();
}
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/includes/header.php');
if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
echo "
        <section class='prfileMenu tabcontent' id='Profiles'>
            <div class='profile_header'>
                <span class='page_title'>Profile Page</span>
                <hr class='page_title_hr'>  
            <div>
            <div class='profile-container-wrapper'>
                <div class='prof-datas-title'>Basic Infos</div>
                <div class='profile-datas-container'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username:</td>
                        <td id='profileUsername'>{$username}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class='prov-delete-prof'>Delete</a>
                            <a class='edit-data'>Edit</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>User ID:</td>
                        <td>{$id}</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Priority:</td>
                        <td id='priority'>unknow</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Joined:</td>
                        <td>{$timestamp}</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Status:</td>
                        <td><span class='prof-status'>active<span></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='profile-container-wrapper'>
                <div class='prof-datas-title'>General</div><br>
                <div class='profile-datas-container'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Real Name:</td>
                        <td>{$realname}</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email:</td>
                        <td>{$email}</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Second Email:</td>
                        <td>".$second_email."</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age:</td>
                        <td>".$age."</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sex:</td>
                        <td>".$sex."</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Country:</td>
                        <td>".$country."</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class='exception-border'>
                        <td>City:</td>
                        <td>".$city."</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='profile-container-wrapper'>
                <div class='prof-datas-title'>Security</div>
                <div class='profile-datas-container'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>New Email:</td>
                        <td>Changes to this email address are delayed by 1 week.</td>
                        <td class='edit-data'>Get</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>New Password</td>
                        <td>unknown</td>
                        <td class='edit-data'>Get</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>New Passkey:</td>
                        <td>Unavailable</td>
                        <td class='edit-data'>Get</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2FA:</td>
                        <td>Disabled</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='profile-container-wrapper'>
                <div class='prof-datas-title'>Advanced</div>
                <div class='profile-datas-container'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Activation Code:</td>
                        <td>6058bf4fa2c2a</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Beta Program:</td>
                        <td>Disabled</td>
                        <td class='edit-data'>Enable</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

";
} else {
echo "
    <section class='prfileMenu tabcontent' id='Profiles'>
        <div class='profile_header'>
            <span class='page_title'>Error: 404</span>
            <hr class='page_title_hr'>  
        <div>
            <div class='centered-tag'>
                <h1 class='error-blank'>404</h1>
                <p>Page not found</p>
                <span>The page you're looking for may have been removed, renamed, or temporarily unavailable. </span>
                <div class='forbidden-backto-button-container'>
                    <a>Back to Dashboard</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </main>
";
}
?>
<script src='/admin/includes/assets/js/adminrank.js'></script>
<script src='/admin/includes/assets/js/productivity_meter.js'></script>
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Is this academic code purely for learning, or for a production site that will see actual real-world users?

Comment: The reason for your issues is that you always bind the logged user: `$stmt->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['id']);`. You never actually use `$_GET['id']` in your query.

Comment: You're also mixing prepared statements and direct parameter injection. Stick to prepared statements whenever you have a parameter in your query.

Comment: The other thing that I would caution on is that it's a security violation to just allow the user to select any other user in the system. What would even be the point of having users if you aren't protecting them? You could validate that the user is in the same group, company, or that the first user has higher level permissions.

Comment: To expand on the previous comment: it's fine to allow users to view other users' profiles, but actions on those should be limited to the owner of the profile and potentially some admin staff.

Comment: It is limited just I pasted an older code. Now only the user can edit or delete their account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must bind $id to your query and check $_GET["id"] exist before it

```
     if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != "") {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
   } else {
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
   }
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT username, realname, password, email, second_email, sex, age,  country, city, timestamp FROM accounts WHERE id = ?');
   $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($username, $realname, $password, $email, $second_email, $sex, $age,         $country, $city, $timestamp);
   $stmt->fetch();
   $stmt->close()
```

;